# nature's good in a cup

Tags: grammar

I was making a smoothie for myself and had just been watching a documentary on the world of marketing and this thought popped into my head.

> Nature's good in a cup

Am I right that the above is incorrect? It should be `Nature's goodness` right?

I was trying to keep it short and snazzy :)

Comment: _Good_ is a perfectly fine noun ("something that possesses desirable qualities, promotes success, welfare, or happiness, or is otherwise beneficial") that can belong to Nature. Nothing objectionable about "Nature's good in a cup."

Comment: oh! so you're saying it is grammatically correct?

Comment: It's entirely unclear to me what you are saying. Is *nature's* a possessive or a contraction? Are you trying to say *This represents the good that is nature, in a cup* or *This shows good qualities of nature, in a cup* or *Nature is good when found in a cup* or *Nature tastes good when it is in a cup*, etc.

Comment: I'm trying to say that _all the good that can be found in nature can be found in this cup_?

Comment: It is brilliant!  Because of the syntactic ambiguity it means two things at once (it is like one of those vase / face drawings that switch appearance). Now you see "Nature is good in a (this)cup;" then you see it means "(All) the good of nature in a cup."  Ingenious.

Comment: @Ciwan Despite the answer you accepted (which is not convincingly argued, if not completely incorrect), yes, "Nature's good in a cup" (which concisely states "All that is desirable and beneficial of Nature in a cup") is grammatically correct. The people who would object to it likely objected to Apple's "Think Different" slogan.

Comment: choster's question is important here.  Do you mean "nature is good" or "the good belonging to nature"??

Comment: Thanks guys, I've learnt a lot from this little thought that I had :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're not right.  Sorry.

First, I don't think it's using "good" as a noun but an adjective.  I believe it's saying something like, "Nature is good (tasty) in a cup."

Second, even if it were using "good" as a noun, it could.  "Good" is a noun as well as an adjective, e.g., "We tried to see *the good* in him."  So "good" could be used to mean "goodness" as it does in this context.